# How to get my button to call a function and count from tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to call a function at every button click,
the function is calling a text from a entrybox and transferring it to new label and every time I click a button the number must increase\increment by 1'
the code runs until I press the button the gives me this error:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python310\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1921, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\NdohAdmin\PycharmProjects\gui\main.py", line 24, in button_clicked
    new += 1
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str
```

This is the code:

```
from tkinter import *

window = Tk()
window.geometry("500x200")
window.title("My first GUI program")

# label head
Head = Label(text="WELCOME TO THE SKIPPING CHALLENGE", font=("Arial", 30, "bold"))
Head.Grid(row=0, column=1)

counter = Label(text="Enter Your target.", font=("Arial", 20, "bold",))
counter.grid()

# Entry box
msay = Entry(width=10)
msay.grid()
msay.get()


# Function to increase
def button_clicked():
    global new
    new = msay.get()
    new += 1

# Button calls a function
button = Button(text="Skip to count", command=button_clicked)
button.grid()

skipping_count = Label(text="Your Counter", font=("Arial", 20, "bold"))
skipping_count.grid()

new = Label(text="0", font=("Arial", 20, "bold"))
new.grid()

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: It's unclear what you want to happen when the `button_clicked()` function is called. The code in your question changes the global `new` variable from a `Label` into the string value that `msay.get()` returns and then tries to add the integer value `1` to that — which clearly makes no sense. This is a separate issue from the `TypeError` you're getting (and just fixing that won't solve it).

Answer (score 2):

`msay.get()` gives you a string type number, You need to convert it to an integer using `int()`

```py
from tkinter import *

window = Tk()
window.geometry("500x200")
window.title("My first GUI program")

# label head
Head = Label(text="WELCOME TO THE SKIPPING CHALLENGE", font=("Arial", 30, "bold"))
Head.grid(row=0, column=1)

counter = Label(text="Enter Your target.", font=("Arial", 20, "bold",))
counter.grid()

# Entry box
msay = Entry(width=10)
msay.grid()
msay.get()


# Function to increase
def button_clicked():
    global new
    new = int(msay.get())
    new += 1

# Button calls a function
button = Button(text="Skip to count", command=button_clicked)
button.grid()

skipping_count = Label(text="Your Counter", font=("Arial", 20, "bold"))
skipping_count.grid()

new = Label(text="0", font=("Arial", 20, "bold"))
new.grid()

window.mainloop()
```

##### Your question is not clear to me, But I write what I understand.

I think this could help you.

```py
from tkinter import *

window = Tk()
window.geometry("500x200")
window.title("My first GUI program")

# label head
Head = Label(text="WELCOME TO THE SKIPPING CHALLENGE", font=("Arial", 30, "bold"))
Head.grid(row=0, column=1)

counter = Label(text="Enter Your target.", font=("Arial", 20, "bold",))
counter.grid()

# Entry box
msay = Entry(width=10)
msay.grid()
msay.get()
start = 0
v = 0

# Function to increase
def button_clicked():
    global start,v # Excess to global variable.
    if msay.get() == '': # Change the value of start to zero and insert 0 inside entry if there is no value inside the entry.
        start=0
        msay.insert(0,'0')
    elif v != int(msay.get()): # Check if value inside entry is change, Then change the value of v and start.
        v = int(msay.get())
        start = int(msay.get())

    new['text'] = start # Change the text of the label
    start+=1 # add 1 to start.
    

# Button calls a function
button = Button(text="Skip to count", command=button_clicked)
button.grid()

skipping_count = Label(text="Your Counter", font=("Arial", 20, "bold"))
skipping_count.grid()

new = Label(text="0", font=("Arial", 20, "bold"))
new.grid()

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: While your answer fixes the `TypeError`, just fixing that issue won't make the OP's code work the way they want.

Comment: @martineau You're right, But the question is not clear to me.

Comment: I hope now this could be the answer to OP's question.

Comment: I agree the what that what the OP wants to happen when the button is clicked is unclear…and asked them for clarification instead of guessing. I'm afraid this is one of those awkward situations where the OP thinks the error they were getting was the only thing preventing their code from doing what they want (whatever that is).

Comment: @martineau I post the second answer, I think this will help OP.

Comment: What you added would likely be more helpful if you explained how it works and/or is different from their code — instead of just some code that does things differently.

Comment: @martineau Okk.